# Dropdown list in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation

I am working on an iPhone app that has a filter list (dropdown list) under the navigation bar that appears when I click on the bar button. Please suggest me how can I do it.

[image]

Comment: create one textfield or search bar , and one tableview below to your navigation bar. After finished searching remove your textfield and tableview.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a number ways to do it, my suggestions would be something similar to as follows:

When you initialise the view controller, your dropdown view is offset and hidden behind the navigation bar. Do this either with Layout Constraints or using the view's frame, depending on your preferred set up.

```
var isAnimating: Bool = false
var dropDownViewIsDisplayed: Bool = false

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let height: CGFloat = self.dropDownView.frame.size.height
    let width: CGFloat = self.dropDownView.frame.size.width
    self.dropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -height, width, height)
    self.dropDownViewIsDisplayed = false
}
```

Then link up an action to the BarButtonItem that, when pressed, displays the view if hidden or hides if visible using an animation.

```
@IBAction func barButtonItemPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem?) {
    if (self.dropDownViewIsDisplayed) {
        self.hideDropDownView()
    } else {
        self.showDropDownView()
    }
}

func hideDropDownView() {
     var frame: CGRect = self.dropDownView.frame
     frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height
     self.animateDropDownToFrame(frame) {
         self.dropDownViewIsDisplayed = false
     }
}

func showDropDownView() {
    CGRect frame = self.dropDownView.frame
    frame.origin.y = self.navigationBar.frame.size.height
    self.animateDropDownToFrame(frame) {
        self.dropDownViewIsDisplayed = true
    }
}

func animateDropDownToFrame(frame: CGRect, completion:() -> Void) {
    if (!self.animating) {
        self.animating = true
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.dropDownView.frame = frame
            }, completion: (completed: Bool) -> Void in {
                self.animating = false
                if (completed) {
                     completion()
                }
            })
    }
}
```

All that is left for you is to define your dropDownView and link it up correctly.

I hope that helps, please comment if there is anything you don't understand

Comment: Thanks for your replay , +1 for the speed answer . I'll check it then i marked as right answer

Comment: I also implemented it this way but on mine I added two UIButtons to a the dropdown UIView. I inserted the drop down UIView below the navigationController.navigationbar. My problem is my click events are not working. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Elliott, Im getting error in the completion Block.. In the "completion: (completed: Bool) -> Void in" line. Saying expected expression in the list of expressions

Answer (score -1):

To use Drop down List with custom View and with Tableview use the below link https://github.com/lminhtm/LMDropdownView

Comment: @abirama that library is in Obj-C, do you have a swift version!?

Comment: You can use Obj-C in Swift Project with the help of bridging header.