# Dropdown animation in Swift - completion block error

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I was following the code listed here: [Dropdown list in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828882/dropdown-list-in-swift)

Namely:

```
func animateDropDownToFrame(frame: CGRect, completion:() -> Void) {
    if (!self.isAnimating) {
        self.isAnimating = true
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.dropDownView.frame = frame
            }, completion: {(completed: Bool) -> Void in
            self.isAnimating = false
            if (completed) {
                completion()
            }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And keep getting the errors on the line with completion:

> Expected ',' separator
>
> Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Note that I changed the completion line somewhat since I thought the brackets were in the wrong place, but don't think that's the issue.

What may be the issue (and what's the best way to have debugged this on my own)?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax, as written, is pretty hard to follow. There may also be a bug with the Swift compiler that makes it unable to parse what you wrote. Swift allows nested functions so you can do something like this:

```
func animateDropDownToFrame(frame: CGRect, completion:() -> Void) {
    func animate() {
        self.dropDownView.frame = frame
    }

    func animationDidComplete(completed : Bool) {
        self.isAnimating = false
        if (completed) {
            completion()
        }
    }

    if (!self.isAnimating) {
        self.isAnimating = true
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: animate, completion: animationDidComplete)
    }
}
```

(I have access to Xcode right now so there may be some typos. Correct as needed)