# iOS-How to set dropdown for a button inside UITableview cell using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having a tableview which contains user registration details.In that i want to set dropdown for city selection.Can you suggest me how to set dropdown inside UITableview using Swift?

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828882/dropdown-list-in-swift

Comment: I tried it.It not works for me.I'm new to iOS.I know how to set dropdown in UIView using tableView.But i want to set dropdown inside tableview.

Answer (score -1):

Download this https://github.com/arunpkumar92/MultiSelectableDropDownBox customize it

Example code is below

```
    let myDataSource = ["Economy", "Geopolitics Geopolitics Geopolitics Geopolitics Geopolitics", "Industry","society"]

    multiSelector("Multiple Select", // Title - Optional
        dataSource: myDataSource,
        selectionType: .Single, // type of selection - Optinal (Default = .Single)
        isMandatory: false, // is that fiel is mandatory - Optional (Default = false)
        inViewController: self,
        atRect: senderButton.frame,
        inView: singleSelectView,
        arrowDirections: .Up, // Direction for iPad - Optinal
        animated: true)
    .singleCompletion = { (result: String!) -> Void in self.singleSelectLabel.text = result }
```