# Custom UITextView Autocomplete Feature

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextview

I am trying to create a custom autocomplete field (like in a search bar) for a science app that allows for a definition to be added to the `UITextView`. The process would go like this.

1. User taps button in Keyboard Accessory and button adds a 'block' in the `UITextView`
2. When typing in the 'block' it shows a `TableView?` underneath with the suggestions of periodic table elements.
3. Once elements are selected either by clicking the suggestion in the TableView (or pressing enter and choosing the first suggestion) a block is made that shows the Periodic Table element name and definition.
   I have quickly mocked up what I am thinking using the notes app BEAR. It has a similar feature just without the last step: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFIba.jpg

I am new to a lot of this so thank you in advance for any suggestions on what the naming conventions of all this is and any related info or explanations as to how I would achieve this.

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828882/dropdown-list-in-swift

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple way to achieve it.

I have used third party library called [DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) to show a dropdown when specific word added into `UITextView`.

```
import UIKit
import DropDown

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    let dropDown = DropDown()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

        if textView.text.last == "#" {

            let endPosition: UITextPosition = textView.endOfDocument

            //Get courser position to show dropdown
            let rect = textView.caretRect(for: endPosition)

            //Create a custom view to provide anchorView to DropDown
            let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y, width: 200, height: 0))
            textView.addSubview(customView)

            dropDown.anchorView = customView  // UIView or UIBarButtonItem

            // The list of items to display. Can be changed dynamically
            dropDown.dataSource = ["Car", "Motorcycle", "Truck"]

            // Action triggered on selection
            dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
                print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
                //remove Custom view as we no longer needed it.
                customView.removeFromSuperview()

                //Set your text accourding to selection from dropdown item.
                textView.text = textView.text.dropLast() + " " + "\(item)"
            }

            dropDown.show()
        }
    }
}
```

I have added comment for explanation.

And your result will be:

[image]

[HERE](https://github.com/KheniDharmesh/Auto-Complete-With-TextView) is the demo project for more info.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for helping me!! How do you think I would achieve making an actual block? so it's in a box with a background and 2 separate text sections like in the video I posted above? I don't necessarily need the text editable just in a contained section... Look forward to hearing from you :) P.S. I can't seem to access your link either...

Comment: I'm also not trying to have it active on typing the hashtag letter but on clicking the button I have in the Keyboard Accessory view it creates a 'block'...

Comment: Repo is public now and you can access it.

Comment: You can perform that action when user click on any option and for 2 separate text sections you can use attributed text. and I am not getting what "I don't necessarily need the text editable just in a contained section" means.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a contained block. Like I show in the video. An actual square with a background and 2 text sections... How would I achieve this?

Comment: Yes there is a another array or data which have a relation with selected item from dropdown. and once user select any item from the list they are pasting data to textview which have a relation with selected item

Comment: Yep, I am wanting a block with a background colour that takes up the whole width of the textview. I show this in the video. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193399/discussion-between-dharmesh-and-a-wip).